# JBOSS Tools for Indigo can't make connection to SQLServer 2008 database

Tags: sql-server, eclipse, database-connection, jboss7.x, jboss-tools

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server 2008 database in Eclipse.

I've tried it with Eclipse Juno and simply used the data source explorer, added a new connection, selected the driver (downloaded from Microsoft's website) and everything went perfectly.

The problem comes when I want to use JBoss Tools (that only exists for Eclipse Indigo).
I do the exact same thing and I obtain this:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)


at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:241)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2243)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:491)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1309)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:214)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:73)
at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.msft.internal.sqlserver.connection.JDBCSQLServerConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCSQLServerConnectionFactory.java:27)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Any ideas of what can this be? And what does JBoss Tools has that Juno's WTP doesn't (I'm considering not using Eclipse Tools because of this, and I'm developing for JBOSS 7.0 and 7.1).

EDIT: I've tried Eclipse Indigo without JBOSS Tools and it works perfectly. So the problem should be in JBoss tools. Is there any other way of doing this? I just want to use Hivernate to reverse engineer the database into entities.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out and I'm still going to use JBoss Tools.
The problem was in the proxy definition in Eclipse, and it's now solved :)